# How to pass dynamically generated data to a different state in Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, dynamically-generated

Question: how do I access a dynamically generated data in scope B, when I go from scope A and generate this data in scope A, using angular's ui-controller. Data is not available when the scope is initialized.

Note: I am fine with showing request data in the URL. I'm looking for the **simplest** way for new state to read data it needs and pass it to server and properly generate its contents.

When the page loads, it fetches data from server and populates scope "tests" with new data. This new data is shown on the page. I create links to scope "test" with this data. Links look like this:

```
<a ui-sref="test({id:test._id})">{{test.name}}</a>
```

On a rendered page it looks like this:

```
<a ui-sref="test({id:test._id})" class="ng-binding" href="#/test/57adc0e30a2ced3810983640">A test</a>
```

The href is correct and points to a database reference of an item. My goal is to have this reference as a variable in scope "test". My state provider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tests', {
        url: '/tests/',
        templateUrl: 'test/index.html',
        controller: 'Test.IndexController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: { activeTab: 'tests' }
    })
    .state('test', {
        url: '/test/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'test/item.html',
        controller: 'Test.ItemController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: { 
            activeTab: 'tests',
            testId: '{id}'
        }
    });
```

So far no matter what I tried I couldn't access "testId" in the "test" scope. It was either "undefined", created errors or returned "itemId: {id}".

My Item.Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function Controller(TestService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.test = null;

        function getTest(id) {
            TestService.GetTestById(id).then(function(test) {
                vm.test = test;
            });
        }

        function initController() {
            getTest(...);
        }

        initController();
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Test.ItemController', Controller);
})();
```

TestService provides http get methods for getting data from server.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function Service($http, $q) {
        var service = {};

        function handleSuccess(res) {
            return res.data;
        }

        function handleError(res) {
            return $q.reject(res.data);
        }

        function GetTestById(_id) {
            var config = {
                params: {
                    testId: _id 
                }
            };
            return $http.get('/api/tests/:testId', config).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
        }

        service.GetTests = GetTests;
        service.GetTestById = GetTestById;

        return service;
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('TestService', Service);

})();
```

I tried $scope - scope is not defined. I tried a number of other techniques, shown by other users with similar success - either "undefined" or error of some sort.

This is based on another person's code so there may be obvious mistakes, please let me know if you find any. If you need more code, let me know - I'll upload it to github (its a messy work in progress at the moment so I'm not sure what should be uploaded).